# Invalid or unexpected token when i try to use wait-for-it.sh

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

```
/thuytinh/backend/wait-for-it.sh:2
# Use this script to test if a given TCP host/port are available
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.18.2
```

My docker compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  database-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nhahang
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ../server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_HOST=database-mysql
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - database-mysql
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "database-mysql:3306", "--", "node", "dist/main.js"]
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.3
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ../admin/dist:/var/www/admin/dist
      - ../client/dist:/var/www/client/dist
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

My docker file in backend:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /thuytinh/backend

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g webpack webpack-cli webpack-node-externals

COPY . .

COPY wait-for-it.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

RUN npm run build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

Wait for mysql to be initialized, then the backend will be initialized and connected to mysql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It appears like that bash script is incorrectly run in node and not in bash.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, you `COPY wait-for-it.sh /usr/local/bin/` and make that copy of the script executable.  When you override the image's command in the Compose file, though, you run `./wait-for-it.sh` out of the current directory.

The `node` image has some complicated behavior where, if the command you give it doesn't appear to be executable, it will automatically run it under `node`.  This is intended to support use cases like `docker run node index.js` without having to repeat the interpreter name.  If the script exists in the current directory (so `COPY . .` includes it in the image) but isn't executable, you'd see the behavior you describe.

Since `/usr/local/bin` is in the default Linux search `$PATH`, the easiest fix is to change the `command:` override to not include the relative path and just the script command name

```yaml
command: ["wait-for-it.sh", ...]
#         ^^ remove ./ here
```

Comment: (I'd also consider refactoring this into an entrypoint wrapper script, so you don't need the `command:` override.)